# Graph dictionary

Tags: python, matrix, graph

I would like to get a Python dictionary of the lists based on an adjacency matrix. Keys are nodes and values are lists of adjcency points.

Here is my code:

```
A=[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

d={}
for row in A:
    for col in A:
        s=A.index(row)
        if sum(row)==0:
            d[s]=[]
        else:
            for i in row:
                l=[]
                h=row.index(i)
                if i==1:
                    l.append(h)
            d[s]=l  

print (d)
```

I should see:

> {0: [0], 1:[], 2:[1, 2]}

As you might guess - my code doesn't work. Your solutions?

Comment: You would have EXACTLY the same behaviour with a dataframe, just that keys would be rows, so don't really understand why you need a dictionary. BUT if you want one it should be trivial to do for rowindex in rows: store row values as list

Comment: I dont get what you do here ... whatfor is the second for loop over A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this might be easier to understand as a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
> A=[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
> {row:[col for col, included in enumerate(cols) if included ] for row, cols in enumerate(A)}

{0: [0], 1: [], 2: [1, 2]}
```

If you want to use loops, you need to loop over the each row, and then each list in the row. Something like:

```
adj = {}

for index, row in enumerate(A):
    adj[index] =  []
    for e_index, edge in enumerate(row):
        if edge:
            adj[index].append(e_index)
```

Every row will have a value, even if it's an empty list. So you don't need the logic with the `sum`, just add the row and an empty list as you enter each row. Then add edges if they exist in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
A=[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
adj = {}

# for all nodes
for node, neighbors in enumerate(A):
    # for all neighbors of this node
    for neighbor, connection in enumerate(neighbors):
        # add to list
        if connection:
            adj[node] = adj.get(node, []) + [neighbor]
for k, v in adj.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
0 [0]
2 [1, 2]
```

Edit: If you are working with graphs I recommend [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html)